# Optimize function with nlm and optim

Tags: r

I have the following function

```
f <- function(a,b) {
    (a - 1) + 3.2/b + 3*log(gamma(a)) + 3*a*log(b);
}
```

I want to optimized this function with `nlm() ,optim() ect...`.

I am trying to do that with:

```
value <- nlm(f,optim(f))
```

However, I get an error message.`cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'` I really would appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works ok for me using both `optim` and `nlm`. I did a little modification

```
f <- function(par) {
  a <- par[1]
  b <- par[2]
  (a - 1) + 3.2/b + 3*log(gamma(a)) + 3*a*log(b);
}

> optim(c(1, .3), fn=f)
$par
[1] 1.399685 0.762025

$value
[1] 3.09904

$counts
function gradient 
      55       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

> nlm(f, c(1,.3))
$minimum
[1] 3.09904

$estimate
[1] 1.3999515 0.7619307

$gradient
[1] 3.096044e-07 3.907985e-07

$code
[1] 1

$iterations
[1] 17
```

Comment: Would it be better to use `optim` and `nlm` toghether?

Comment: Thx a lot for this examples! I also read in the docu that there is `nlminb()`.

Comment: You can use either `optim` or `nlm`, I dont understand what you mean with use `optim` and `nlm` toghether There is also `maxLik` in maxLik package, this is a wrapper of `optim`.